# Create a Replica of Content DB and use it as content database of new web application in the same SPFarm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, backup, content-database

Am having a Single Server Farm Environment wherein I am having 1 WFE and 1 SQL Server machine . in the SQL server box, I have taken a backup of SharePoint's 
web application's content DB.

- Content DB of web web application is `"wss_content_npdwebapp"`.
- The backup of this content db, I have take is `"wss_content_npdwebapp_june14_backup.bak"`

Now my question is, how can I use this backed-up content DB as a content database of another web application in this same server farm?
can I create a replica of this content DB? and once this replica is created I can mount this content DB as my new web application's DB.

If I restore it on a new content DB, it won't allow me to do that, as the GUID of existing content DB conflicts with the restored-renamed content DB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's correct, you can't restore a content database to another web application on the same farm because `the Content Database GUID is already existing`.

**So to overcome this issue, you have to do the following:**

- Create your new web application
- Create the root site collection.
- Backup and restore the site collections from source content database to new one using PowerShell

**To Get site collections list within content database**

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All  -ContentDatabase "Content Database Name" | select url
```

**To Backup site collection**

```
Backup-SPSite https://source-sitecoll-url -Path "C:\Backup\sourcesitecollection.bak"
```

**To Restore site collection**

```
Restore-SPSite https://destination-sitecoll-url -Path "C:\Backup\sourcesitecollection.bak"
```

Comment: But cant we change the GUID of backed-up content db ? i heard / read somewhere that. its possible to apply/assign a  new GUID for the backed-up content db . So once the new GUID is assigned , i can positively go-ahead and create a new appln and mount it to this  content  db .Thats what i am looking for, how to apply/assign a new GUID to the copy of the existing db.

Comment: Trust me :) It's impossible to mount the same content database to another web application in the same farm, even you find how to change the DB GUID as you have read, you will face another issue that not related to DB GUID but in this case, it will be related to Site GUID. so based on my humble knowledge the only solution to achieve your goal what I have provided in my answer, hope it help :)

Comment: OK, thanks ! @M.Qassas . will perform the steps in my farm and revert the results here. :-)

Comment: You are welcome, take your time:)

Comment: one question am having : is this possible to create a new content db and this content db becomes the db for the newly restored site collection ?!

Comment: Yes, it's possible for the new web application. but you should first lock the other Content database to make sure that the restored database has been created to this content database, to lock other content database check steps at  https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/28/lock-down-the-project-web-app-content-database/